# How to fix the modal toggle using event emitter in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-zorro-antd

***header.component.html***

```
<app-change-password
  [toggleVisiblity]="passwordDialogueVisible"
  (passwordSubmit)="savePassword($event)"
></app-change-password>
```

***header.component.ts***

```
passwordDialogueVisible = false;
  togglePasswordDialog(event?: any) {
    if (this.avatarDropdownVisible) {
      this.avatarDropdownVisible = false;
    }

    this.passwordDialogueVisible = true;
  }

  savePassword(event: any) {
    this.user
      .changeCurrentUserPassword(event)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(
        (res: Response) => { },
        (err: Error) => {
          console.log('password not accepted');
        }
      );
  }
```

***user-setting.html***

```
<li class="configuration-body--menu-item action">
          <span class="label" (click)="togglePassword()">Change Password</span>
          <span class="control"></span>
        </li>
```

***user-setting.ts***

```
@Output() changePassword: any = new EventEmitter();

    togglePassword() {
        console.log('change password');
        this.changePassword.emit(undefined);
      }
```

***change-password.html***

```
<ng-template #modalForm>
  <form nz-form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!user" [ngTemplateOutlet]="currentUser"></ng-container>
    <ng-template #currentUser>
      <nz-form-item>
        <nz-form-label nzFor="old">
          <span translate>Old Password</span>
        </nz-form-label>
        <nz-form-control>
          <input nz-input name="old" type="password" id="old" autocomplete formControlName="old"
            [placeholder]="'Enter Old Password' | translate" />
          <nz-form-explain *ngIf="formGroup.get('old')?.dirty && formGroup.get('old')?.errors">
            <span translate>Old password is required!</span>
          </nz-form-explain>
        </nz-form-control>
      </nz-form-item>
    </ng-template>

    <nz-form-item>
      <nz-form-label nzFor="password">
        <span translate>New Password</span>
      </nz-form-label>
      <nz-form-control>
        <input nz-input name="password" type="password" id="password" autocomplete formControlName="password"
          [placeholder]="'Enter New Password' | translate" />
        <nz-form-explain *ngIf="formGroup.get('password')?.dirty && formGroup.get('password')?.errors">
          <span translate *ngIf="formGroup.get('password')?.value.length === 0">Password is required!</span>
          <span translate *ngIf="formGroup.get('password')?.value.length > 0">Minimum of 8 characters!</span>
        </nz-form-explain>
      </nz-form-control>
    </nz-form-item>

    <nz-form-item>
      <nz-form-label nzFor="newPassword">
        <span translate>Confirm New Password</span>
      </nz-form-label>
      <nz-form-control>
        <input nz-input name="newPassword" type="password" id="newPassword"
          [placeholder]="'Confirm New Password' | translate" formControlName="newPassword" autocomplete />
        <nz-form-explain *ngIf="
              (formGroup.get('newPassword')?.dirty && formGroup.get('newPassword')?.errors) ||
              (formGroup.get('password')?.valid &&
                formGroup.get('password')?.value !== formGroup.get('newPassword')?.value)
            ">
          <span translate>Password did not match!</span>
        </nz-form-explain>
      </nz-form-control>
    </nz-form-item>
  </form>
</ng-template>
```

***change-password.ts***

```
  @Input() toggleVisiblity: boolean;
  @Input() user: any;
  @Output() passwordSubmit = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @ViewChild('modalForm') modalForm: TemplateRef<any>;

  _visible = false;

  modalRef: NzModalRef;
  formGroup: FormGroup = this.generateForm();

 @Input()
  set visibility(status: boolean) {
    this._visible = status;

    if (status) {
      this.formGroup = this.generateForm();
      this.generateContainer();
    }
  }
  get visibility() {
    return this._visible;
  }

ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.toggleVisiblity) {
      this.generateForm();
      this.generateContainer();

      this.toggleVisiblity = undefined;
    }
  }

 generateContainer() {
    const _this = this;

    this.modalRef = this.modalService.create({
      nzTitle: this.translate.instant('Change Password'),
      nzContent: this.modalForm,
      nzOkText: 'Save',
      nzOkDisabled: !this.formGroup.valid,
      nzOnOk: () => {
        _this.returnPassword();
        _this.modalRef.destroy();
      },
      nzOnCancel: () => {
        _this.modalRef.destroy();
      }
    });
  }
```

What I'm trying to do here is to fix the change password modal toggle. the first attempt clicking the change password its working but when second attempt it doesn't show the modal. I click the change password many times but it doesn't work. it only run once but after that it doesn't work. but when I refresh/reload the page its working again after first attempt then it doesn't work again. 
how to fix the modal toggle?

Comment: Where is the changePassword event registered? What happens after it's emitted?

Comment: @Jacob here's the video https://streamable.com/h92r6r

Comment: I think we need more code. Parent component html? Where is visibility/toggleVisiblity set?

Comment: I added the header.component @Jacob

Comment: I still don't think that's all the relevant code. Where is `togglePasswordDialog()` called? Sorry, I might be missing something. Have you put a `console.log()` in `togglePasswordDialog()` to make sure it's being called for every click?

Comment: @Jacob yes, I already try to ```console.log()``` and its working. also inside the condition I already tried to add ```console.log()```

Comment: `this.passwordDialogueVisible` in header.component never gets set back to false, so ngOnChanges() doesn't get called again.

Comment: should I put the ```console.log()``` before the ```this.passwordDialogueVisible = true;``` or after?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215153/discussion-between-panda-and-jacob). @Jacob